# android - How to Exit from the application

Tags: android

My Application have 20 activities. Here i want to implement the how to exit from the application when you click on the button(like Logout). it means if you click on the menu button any where of our application then it shows the one button. if click on that then directly comes out from the application. how to implement it.

thanks

Comment: This would help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089496/android-app-exit-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well naresh you can do something like that
first finish the activity from which you are closing application this.finish(); secondly and most impotantly always set a flag i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
this clear top when you switch from one activity to another activity and as you know every activity is kept in stack to so this flag remove old activity from top and push new activity in top so around your whole application only one activity is kept in stack

and if this does not work put the whole application in background by avtivityname.moveTaskToBack(); this will move your whole app in back ground but only one drawback when you start your activity it will show your that activity from which you have moved back

Answer (score 0):

```
System.exit(0);
```

should work, don't forget Java common functions work on android, there isn't only the android library!

As for the button being in the menu in every activity, you could create a class derived from Activity which creates and handles the menu properly, and make every other activity inherit that derived activity.

Comment: What is the problem? `System.exit(0);` should kill the process when executed.

Comment: click on the button it finish the current activity and after that it shows the previous activity

Answer (score 0):

First finish the activity from which you are closing application: `this.finish();`. Secondly and most impotantly always set a flag `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` This clears top when you switch from one activity to another activity. As you know every activity is kept in a stack to so this flag removes old activity from the top and pushes new activity to the top so around your whole application only one activity is kept in the stack.

If this does not work, put the whole application in background with `avtivityname.moveTaskToBack();`. This will move your whole app to the background. One drawback: when you start your activity it will show your that activity from which you have moved back.