# Extended Application class - Force Close on Restart Android

Tags: android-manifest, android

I have my `AppMain` class [My class Name] that extended the `Application` class in my app. That have some Globals.
I have mentioned inside the manifest. and my app running normal. I have exit button in my app to quit it using `System.exit(0);` .

After that when I start my app using **Recent Apps** option, it just crashed.
( FYI. Hold down the Home key and the recent apps will appear)

Starting the app from **Apps List** it is fine.

How can I fix this?

Here part of my manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".activity.MainApp"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

**Edit:**

Crash Log:

```
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {xxx.xxx.xxx..HomeActvity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at com.xxx.xxxx.xxx.DatabaseManager.selectFieldsFrom(DatabaseManager.java:161)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at com.xxx.xxxx.xxx.DBUtils.retrieveFromStore(DBUtils.java:75)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at com.xxx.xxxx.xxx.DBController.getAllWishList(DBController.java:407)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at xxx.xxxx.xxx.HomeActvity.retrieveFromListTable(HomeActvity.java:441)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at xxx.xxxx.xxx.HomeActvity.onResume(HomeActvity.java:642)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
04-16 19:04:59.416: E/AndroidRuntime(19649):    ... 12 more
```

This is because the app not starting from splash when starting from recent apps.DB is released on `System.exit(0);` so showing null Pointer Exception.

**UPDATE:**

The app force closed because I set the splash screen and Home screen activity properties to `Single Task` . After removing this it working fine.

Comment: exchange `System.exit(0);` with `finish()` or drop that alltogether. Apps don't need an exit button.

Comment: @zapl they need exit button if it handles some resource release, by default android apps are stored in memory when enough operation memory is available, they are released when system require resources

Comment: @zapl I tried that working fine. but the app still running in the background.

Comment: @Bartek you can release resources in `onPause` etc too. Market, Facebook, Whatsapp, Mediaplayers etc will need to handle resources as well and they have no exit button I know of.

Comment: @zapl agree, i just wanted to point out that sometimes exit button is needed

Comment: Exception is quite self-explained (NullPointerException), what is the code at com.xxx.xxxx.xxx.DatabaseManager.selectFieldsFrom(DatabaseManager.java:161)?

Comment: @yorkw that is my package name. I just hid it.

Comment: Got to re-iterate what @zapl said: you should never call `System.exit()`. Always call `finish()` in your `Activity` implementations and call `stopSelf()` in your Service implementations. Fix your NullPointerException and the crash will stop happening.

Answer (score 1):

The app isn't actually running if it isn't consuming processor time (either running a service or presenting an `Activity` to the user).  It may be in memory but Android's memory management model is designed that way and the app will be killed if something else needs the memory.  `onPause` is a good indication that you may soon exit, and `onDestroy` should free up any resources that an exit button would.

If you absolutely must exit, you can use `finish()` instead, and/or try using the `excludeFromRecents` or `noHistory` flags in the manifest to avoid the crash.  There should be a few others you can play around with, too.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089496/android-app-exit-button) and the [Process Lifecycle section](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle) of the developer docs.

Comment: It's in the `<activity>` element of the manifest:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html  But you should re-evaluate your design, or tell us more about it so we can suggest alternatives.