# Opening my application from Google Play App crashes on exit

Tags: android, android-intent, foreground, google-play

I have option to open my app Google Play page inside my app. When clicking open button in Google Play My app launches again. (From Splash screen)

When I am exiting my app it crashed. I tried put singleTask flag to my Home activity. It actually worked fine. But arised another [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174892/extended-application-class-force-close-on-restart-android). So I need to know is:

Is there any option to put flag in my Market calling Intent to notify that the app is already launched and just bring it front on clicking Open button?

Here how am I calling GooglePlay app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(marketUrl));
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot find Android Market",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

**EDIT**

My market url: `market://details?id=com.foo.bar`

This will directly redirect to my apps Installation page.

Answer (score 0):

use this code..

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(https://play.google.com/store);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```